# What type of websocket react-native use?

Tags: react-native, websocket

I can't find in the docs what are they using?
Is it some native android implementation?

Is it websockets/ws? socket.io? websocket ++ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [Android](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/websocket/WebSocketModule.java) it uses [OkHttp WebSockets](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

On [iOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTWebSocketModule.m), it's a [custom implementation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/WebSocket/RCTSRWebSocket.m).