# Is there a way for my library to use WebSockets in both React Native and React on the Web?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, websocket

I'm writing a cross-platform (i.e. both native and web) React library that needs to use websockets.

The issue is that I can't find any documentation on whether or not I can just use the built in version of the WebSocket class and still have it work without issue.

From what I can gather from the React Native docs, React Native exposes its own version of the WebSocket class, which exposes all the same methods as the one implemented in browsers, but I have no way of knowing if they both just reference the same code, or if the compiler is smart enough to figure out to use the correct one or not.

What I'm trying to say is that I don't know if I can just expose the DOM types in my tsconfig and hope for the best or if there's a best practice correct way of doing this.

I don't want to include React Native as a dependency for the people who don't need it.

Comment: In browser and in a React Native mobile app, WebSocket class is a global. You don't need to import it. Both interfaces should be very similar if not identical. Why do you think a browser user would need react native dependencies?

Comment: @AliMertÇakar because my editor doesn't recognise it unless I import the browser types; so I'm worried there might be some compatibility issues

Comment: It seems like they use different libraries on ios/android. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643804/what-type-of-websocket-react-native-use . It should not matter though, it is not likely that authors of these libraries deviated. have you `yarn add @types/react-native`?. this packages has types for WebSocket.

Comment: @AliMertÇakar I just added the dom types, hoping they're the same. The React Native docs for websockets points to the MDN documentation page, so it seems they based theirs off of the dom version

Comment: Of course, it is a web api after all

Comment: Yeah, but the question is mostly if the library is going to even work across platforms if I do this. I don't know enough about JS engine internals to know if there'd be anything in the way of doing it like this